# VueJS 2.5 and TypeScript enhancements

Tags: typescript, vue.js

VueJS 2.5 is out, and I was waiting for [TypeScript enhancements](https://medium.com/the-vue-point/upcoming-typescript-changes-in-vue-2-5-e9bd7e2ecf08), but after upgrading required dependencies, I really can't see any enhancements.

From what i've read this should display a type error, because msg is a number

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  export default {
    data: function () {
      return {
        msg: 1
      }
    },
    methods: {
      test: function (): number {
        return this.msg.indexOf('App')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

But it actually gives no error, exactly like in previous version. Any clue ? Where are the new TypeScript features ?

Answer (score 1):

It is important to have a tsconfig.json and set "strict" to true. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Recommended-Configuration

Comment: "strict": true do the job, but it also check other possible errors I don't want to check. 

I'll stick to "noImplicitThis": true.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default Vue.extend({
    // data
    // methods
})
```

Type inference for `this` in Vue component could only happen when using 
 canonical Vue API.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work any better with this notification.

Answer (score 0):

`noImplicitThis` must be set to `true` in `tsconfig.json`. `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` option can also be removed.